# Is it okay to pass an endpoint string to a repository?

Tags: java, database, design-patterns, architecture, repository-pattern

I have a question regarding the repository design pattern. Let's say I have a datatype `Foo`. In several places in my application, I must fetch a list of `Foo` from a remote database. For example, let's say I need to fetch a list of trending `Foo`s and somewhere else a list of the most recent `Foo`s.  In my mind I have two options:

- I could define two repository classes, one called `TrendingFoosRepository` which fetches from `/foos/trending` and another called `RecentFoosRepository` which fetches from `/foos/recent`.
- However, since `TrendingFoosRepository` and `RecentFoosRepository` do exactly the same thing just at different endpoints, I could define one repository class called `FoosRepository` which takes in an `endpoint` argument, and instantiate `FoosRepository('/foos/trending')` and `FoosRepository('/foos/recents')`.

To me, the second option is more concise and reusable and is therefore preferable. However, something feels odd to me about passing in endpoints into a repository. Is this antipattern? If so, why and what is the alternative?

Comment: Why not have a single Foo repository and `/foos` endpoint, and then pass in trending or recent as a request param?

Comment: @Scott that makes sense, but I wonder how versatile that is. For example, what if I want to fetch a specific user's `Foo`s (e.g. `/users/1/foos`)? Wouldn't it be better to have separate endpoints for these use cases instead of cramming all of the parameters into a single endpoint?

Comment: There's still nothing wrong with `/users/1/foos?trending` or something similar. My basic reasoning is that "trending" and "recent" aren't separate entities, they're just types of `Foo`

Comment: Why do you think that it can be an antipattern?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use `enum` [instead of magic strings](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/365339/what-is-wrong-with-magic-strings).

```
enum Popularity { 
    TRENDING,
    RECENTS
}
```

and use it as a parameter in your method:

```
FoosRepository(Popularity popularity)
```

In my view, using `enum` is a little bit cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Let's forget for a minute that we are talking about repositories.

So, you have described two options:

1. Multiple separate classes with tiny difference between them
2. A single, parameterizable class

Let's do a trade of ananlyzis

### Multiple separate classes

#### Pros

- They can evolve separately
- A bug in one class will not affect others
- A n+1 variant can be independently introduced

#### Cons

- Might be code duplication
- Harder to maintain
- (Harder to find all usage/references)

### Single, parameterizable class

#### Pros

- Single codebase which is multi purpose
- Single place to fix a "common" bug
- Might be easier to understand the system

#### Cons

- If it is too generic then it can harm legibility
- You might end up

  - with a god class with too many responsibilities
  - having too many parameters
  - with a handful of branching logic depending on the parameter(s)
- In order to solve the previous issues you might split the code into multiple classes

---

So, if you choose

- **multiple separate classes** over *single, parameterizable class* then you prefer **flexibility** over code *reusability*
- **single, parameterizable class** over *multiple separate classes* then you prefer **configurability** over code *evolvability*

Whatever decision you make please add a comment to your solution to explain *why did you choose X over Y* or *why did you exclude Y, Z* during the evaluation of the problem space. This reasoning can't be read from the codebase.